# Where do you place all your files for Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I completed the quickstart tutorial, but I feel really unclear on a few things. I started the guide initially expecting everything to be on my remote server, but it actually seems to be a guide for a local setup. I have everything on my server, and I have the hosts file on my local computer routing to the server, for ex. this is the entry in my hosts file `server-ip quickstart.local`.

1) Currently, I have everything beneath `public_html`. Where should I put all the Zend files (bin, demos, incubator, etc..)? `www/public_html/[zend-files]`,`www/public_html/quickstart/`

2) Where do I put the quickstart (project) folder? Am I supposed to create an index.php that routes to the public folder in the project folder? At the moment, it is at `public_html/quickstart/`.

I feel silly and embarrassed for asking, because I feel like this is something really obvious.

Comment: Demo is just demo =D I don't need it. The bin folder with zf.sh and zf.bat only matters if you're planning to use the command line helper to create your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you'll need only the Zend folder, which is the library itself.

On the `public_html` you need to put only the files located in the `public` folder of your project.

Folders like `application` and `library` should stay out of public_html.

For example

`/home/my_project/public_html` (public folder from zend)

`/home/my_project/private` (the other files, like application and library)

Instead of put the Zend library inside your project `library` folder, you can put it on the php `include_path`.

**The second option**, maybe the best, is to configure your virtual hosts and set the `public` folder (application public folder) as the root folder for your domain `quickstart-local`

So, you will end up with `/home/my_project/public` as your root folder and `/home/my_project/application` as your private folder.

You'll need to setup your `index.php` and `application.ini` with the appropriated paths.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you work with more than one framework version at a time, using symlinks becomes a good option. It is also much better for development than using the include path because you automatically have code assist for ZF code. We organize our projects as follows:

```
/application
/httpdocs
/library
    /Project
    /Zend (->symlink to the Zend folder of the needed version)
    /ZendX (->dito)
/tests
```

And now, if you're about to say that 'symlinks' don't work on Windows, don't say it. It's utter rubish. [It works perfectly well](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).